# Changing color of a python scatter plot based on the value at corresponding points of a separate array

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter

This is a very complicated question so I will see if I can ask it in a way that makes sense.

Background info: I am taking results that come from a script that retrieves data by scanning (in a grid-like format) over two parameters. Those two parameters are stored in arrays that correspond to each other.

For example, they would look like this:

`[[10 10 10]

 [20 20 20]

 [30 30 30]]`

and

`[[25 35 40]

 [25 35 40]

 [25 35 40]]`

and are set up that way so that each corresponding location in the 2-d array gets scanned. When the data is analyzed, the script then fills two  2-d arrays with identical dimensions with some calculated values which I will call x and y respectively.

Each corresponding index of the new 2-d arrays is plotted in a scatter plot.

Now I am trying to change the color of some, but not all of the points, based on the value of a number in the corresponding spot of another 2-d array. For example, in pseudocode:

```
if value at same location in newArray > 9 and value at same location in newArray < 10:
     change color of point
```

Since the scatter plot is not created with a for loop, I am unsure of how to make this happen.

Comment: [scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) will set the color of markers based on the value of a separate array. Use the argument c and cmap to encode to color information.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors

colorMap = plt.get_cmap('Spectral')
print(colorMap)
def getColor(v1, v2):
    if v2 < 40 and v2 > 33  : 
        return 0    
    else :
        return 1 / (v1 + v2)

def getSize(v1,v2):
    return 5 * (v1 + v2)

a1 = [[10,10,10],[20,20,20],[30,30,30]]
a2 = [[25,35,40],[20,34,42],[18,32,45]]

zipped = [list(zip(x,y)) for x,y in zip(a1,a2)]
size = [[getSize(m,n) for m,n in zip(x,y)] for x,y in zip(a1,a2)]
color = [[getColor(m,n) for m,n in zip(x,y)] for x,y in zip(a1,a2)]

plt.scatter(a1,a2,size, color, cmap=colorMap)
```

This takes the two arrays and creates mappings for the color and size at the a1,a2 point. You would need to set the colors as needed. You can change the color mapping by [using this link to reference others.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)

I hope I was on the right path?